# Get title of selected tab in UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I have set the title for all five of my tabs in my AppDelegate file.  I would like to access that title in another view within my application.  I have the code below to output to the log window the selected index of that selected tab but what I'd really like to get is the title for that tab.  I did have a look through the UITabBarController Class Reference and I didn't see anything that would allow me to do this.

What I am trying to avoid is some sort of switch or if...else statement where I hardcode values I have already manually set in another file.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"The currently selected tab has an index of: %d", appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex);

}
```

This code works as intended.  It would just be ideal to see the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIViewController* vc = appDelegate.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
NSString* tabTitle = vc.tabBarItem.title;
```

If the code is in the selected view controller it's even easier:

```
NSString* tabTitle = self.tabBarItem.title;
```

Comment: the self.tabBarItem.title gave me the title of the view controller not the actual tab.  I have set the title of my view controller for the tab like this: MyViewController *msc = [[MyViewController alloc] initwithLeftVC:rvc rightVC:dvc];
 msc.title=@"Salads";