# Get the title of the tab selected in UITabBarController at application launch

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to get the tab title at application launch.

I can do this to read the tabBarItem.title when the user changes tabs:

```
func tabBarController(
        tabBarController: UITabBarController,
        didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

    UserActivity.trackScreen(name: viewController.tabBarItem.title)

}
```

This method does not fire for the initial selection. I tried this approach in `UITabVarController`'s `viewDidLoad` method.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UserActivity.trackScreen(name: self.selectedItem.title) // I think this is not set yet, it is nil.
}
```

This does not work.

How do I get the selected tab bar item, or the tab bar item that *will* be selected, on app launch?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182631/get-title-of-selected-tab-in-uitabbarcontroller

Comment: @johnykumar not related. the tab is not "selected" at the time of `viewDidLoad`. `selectedViewController` is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Doing an action on the "selected" tab is a special case for the first launch, because the delegate method `didSelectViewController` does not fire.

*If* (and this might be a big "if") you can assume the first tab is the one that is selected on app launch, this code will work for handling the first-launch case:

```
    if let vcs = self.viewControllers {
        var firstVC = vcs[0] as UIViewController
        UserActivity.trackScreen(name: firstVC.tabBarItem.title)
    }
```

This works for me. Open to better answers.